# Cocos2d - Actions and Animations are not paused

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

When I do this:

```
[gameLayer pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

Most of the game pauses, but the sprites that are undergoing this action do not pause spinning:

```
[sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:5.0 angle: 360]]];
```

Also, those sprites that are running CCAnimations do not stop animating:

```
CCAnimation *theAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:theFrames delay:0.1];
CCSprite *theOverlay = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"whatever.png"];                
self.theAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:theAnim]];
```

How can I get these to pause when the game is paused? I would expect “pauseSchedulerAndActions” to pause actions, but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: have you tried [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pauseSchedulerAndActions is not recursive, so it will only affect actions and schedules on the node you are pausing, not it's children.

if your scene/layer is shallow, you could probably just get away with looping through the layer's children and calling (pause/resume)SchedulerAndActions on each, otherwise, if you have a deeper graph, you'll probably want to call it recursively. I wrote up a small test and this worked for me:

```
-(void) pauseSchedulerAndActions: (BOOL) pause forNodeTree:(id)parentNode shouldIncludeParentNode:(BOOL)includeParent
{
    if(includeParent)
    {
        (pause) ? [parentNode pauseSchedulerAndActions] : [parentNode resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    }

    for( CCNode *cnode in [parentNode children] )
    {
        (pause) ? [cnode pauseSchedulerAndActions] : [cnode resumeSchedulerAndActions];

        if(cnode.children.count > 0)
        {
            [self pauseSchedulerAndActions:pause forNodeTree:cnode shouldIncludeParentNode:NO]; // on recurse, don't process parent again
        }
    }
}
```

so in your case you could try calling this method and passing in your gameLayer

Comment: Yes, this works. Nice one. Is there any advantage to doing this instead of [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]?

Comment: If you pause the director, it pauses everything, but there could be a situation where you want to run actions or animations in another layer while the other layer is paused. For example, maybe pause the game layer, but keep animating a score label in a HUD layer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];` It should pause all animations and movements.